# Progressbar is not updating the value when click on Back button

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a progressbar in my application. Im calling an intent service for downloading a large size of file. Progress bar is updating properly when the service starts downloading. When i click on back button from the device the intent service is still running in the background and progressbar count is also updating in the background, but when i open the application again the progressbar is not updating the value even though the progressbar count starts from where i has left. Could you please help me to resolve this?

This is the progress bar im having in Layout file,

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:progress="1" />
```

This is my java file where im updating the progressbar. progress intent will have the current count for progress update.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    updateReceiver = new CheckNetworkConnectivity(
            new NetworkReceiverCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onNetworkReceived(int status) {
                    networkStaus = status;
                    if (networkStaus == 0) {

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Download interrupted due to network issue.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        onCallService(fileLength, currentDate, downloaded, Constants.downloadStatus);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Start downloading....",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    registerReceiver(updateReceiver, new IntentFilter(
        ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

    activity = this;

}

private void onCallService(long downloaded, String lastModifiedDate, long size, int downloadStatus) {
    mReceiver = new DownloadResultReceiver(new Handler());
    mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, this,
            DownloadBackgroundService.class);

    String url = "";

    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    intent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
    intent.putExtra("downloaded", downloaded);
    intent.putExtra("downloadStatus", downloadStatus);
    intent.putExtra("size", size);
    intent.putExtra("lastModifiedDate", lastModifiedDate);

    startService(intent);

}

@Override
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + "/100");
    progressBar2.invalidate();
    progressBar2.setProgress(progress);
    progressBar2.isFocused();
    Log.d("DownloadService", "Progress bar is updating : " + progress);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {

    progressBar = (TextProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setMax(100);

    progressBar.setText(String.valueOf(0) + "/100");
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {

    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(updateReceiver);
}
```

Comment: post your full java code will better for helping

Comment: Have added @PhanDinhThai

Answer (score 0):

Please change:

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

to

`android:layout_width="match_parrent"`

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the modified value in logs, and if only its not visible in the output, try progressBar.invalidate();

Comment: Not working. I can see the modified values but still updating in progressbar

Comment: In your code, you are invalidating first and then setting the progress. Please  check that.

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at activity life cycle below : 
[image]

> when i open the application again the progressbar is not updating the value even though the progressbar count starts from where i has left

When you quit application by click back button, every resource belong to activity will be destroyed. And then when you open application again, your resource will be re-provide again. That means when you open app again, your progress bar will be initialize as a new instance when you call `progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);`

I suggest solution that every times you receive the value of downloading progress, save it into Database or preference then restore it when you open application:

```
@Override
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
int progress = resultData.getInt("progress"); // <---- SAVE THIS VALUE
progressBar.setProgress(progress);
progressBar.setMax(100);
progressBar.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + "/100");
progressBar2.invalidate();
progressBar2.setProgress(progress);
progressBar2.isFocused();
Log.d("DownloadService", "Progress bar is updating : " + progress);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
progressBar2.setProgress(progress); // GET SAVED VALUE AND SET IT INTO PROGRESS
```

Comment: But int progress = resultData.getInt("progress"); // <---- SAVE THIS VALUE in logs the progress value is printing correctly even if i click the back button

Comment: yes, That's why you should save that value. When you click back, progress is no longer to exist

Comment: Its working fine whan i open the application again. Its showing the progress bar at the same percentage value where i left. but its not updating the value in onReceiveResult method. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong thread.
"onReceiveResult" is an async event, i.e. probably will not be in the UI thread.
Use mActivity.runOnUiThread to update your UI.